# Extended Report - Line Item report for price sets final line concatenating all records

Tags: civireport

The Extended report  Line Item report for price sets was working perfectly fine till recently.

Now the last line is concatenating all first name and last names.  See Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Pradeep's solution worked as outlined below This is because of full group by mode. I feel the latest version of CiviCRM group bys with fields that are mentioned in sort by(order by). Try after clearing the sorting fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of full group by mode. I feel the latest version of CiviCRM group bys with fields that are mentioned in sort by(order by). Try after clearing the sorting fields.

Comment: So can we close this as answered?